# header and table body are not in proper alignment datatable

Tags: css, angularjs, datatables, scroller

```js
//In dtOption I am giving 
   .withOption('scrollY','auto')
```

```html
<table datatable dt-columns="dtColumns" dt-options="dtOptions"  style="width:100%;"></table>
```

But due to this, the header and remaining body are not in proper alignment. 
I tried various options but the issue is not fixed. Please suggest something what to do to fix that problem. I have attached the screenshot of the table.
[image]

Comment: It appears there is a scrollbar on the right side. Why's that? That's your issue.

Comment: Also, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, I can't add any example or fiddle as it's a long project. My problem is that columns of header and table body are not in proper alignment. Like in my screenshot td of column 3

Answer (score 0):

A work around is:

```
$('#DataTableID').DataTable({
  //"scrollX": true,            
  "initComplete": function (settings, json) {  
    $("#DataTableID").wrap("<div style='overflow:auto; width:100%;position:relative;'></div>");            
  },
});
```